# Scala: how to fix java.lang.NoSuchMethodException when invoking fun with mix(Int,string,list)

Tags: scala

Let's i code speaking:)

```
 class TagCalculation {
    def test_string(arg1: String,arg2: String) = arg1 + " " + arg2
    def test_int(arg1: Int,arg2: Int) = arg1 + arg2
    def test_mix1(arg1:Int,arg2:String) = "test mix1"
    def test_mix2(arg1:Int,arg2:String,arg3:List[Any]) = "test mix2"
  }
val get_test = new TagCalculation
//test mix2
val test_mix2_para = Array(1, "aa",List(1,2))
val argtypes4 = test_mix2_para.map(_.getClass)
val method4 = get_test.getClass.getMethod("test_mix2", argtypes4: _*)
```

Then the error outputs:

> scala>     val argtypes4 = test_mix2_para.map(*.getClass) argtypes4:
>   Array[Class[*]] = Array(class java.lang.Integer, class
>   java.lang.String, class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)
>
> scala>     val method4 = get_test.getClass.getMethod("test_mix2",
>   argtypes4: _*) java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   $iwC$$iwC$TagCalculation.test_mix2(java.lang.Integer,
>   java.lang.String, scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1678)    at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:26)  at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:31)

Could somebody give me some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, and found that it worked by using certain types and telling the compiler exactly what you were up to.  In your case you can use a `java.lang.Integer` instead of a regular `Int` and additionally get really specific with the List type.  This example is working:

```
class TagCalculation {
  def test(arg1: java.lang.Integer, arg2: String, arg3: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon[Any]) = "test mix2"
}

val getTest = new TagCalculation

val arg1: java.lang.Integer = 10
val arg2: String = "foobar"

// Just making a List[Any]
val arg3: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon[Any] = scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.apply('z', List("foo", 10))

val method = getTest.getClass.getMethod("test", arg1.getClass, arg2.getClass, arg3.getClass)
method.invoke(getTest, arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Unfortunately I don't know why this is the case.

Comment: Works well! You’re one in a million

Comment: No implicit conversions are involved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `getMethod` with exactly the classes the method is declared with, it doesn't work otherwise:

```
get_test.getClass.getMethod("test_mix2", classOf[Int], classOf[String], classOf[List[Any]])
```

(the type parameter to `List` does not matter because of type erasure). If you look at `argtypes4`, it doesn't contain these classes: putting `1` into `Array` together with objects boxes it to `java.lang.Integer`, and `List(1, 2)` returns a `::` (which is translated to `$colon$colon` because `:` is not a legal character in a JVM identifier) which is a subclass of `List`.

Comment: hi, is there also a way to handle method4.invoke(get_test,test_mix2_para:_* ) flexibly  if val method4 = get_test.getClass.getMethod("test_mix2", classOf[Int], classOf[String], classOf[List[Any]]). It would be "<console>:39: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[Any]
 required: Array[_ <: Object]"

Comment: Answered at your other question.